# I see an angular2 'bind' function defined in angular2/angular2.d.ts - did it used to be in 'angular2/di.d.ts?

Tags: dependency-injection, bind, angular

Many of the samples I have seen for angular2 have the following import statement:

```
import {bind} from 'angular2/di';
```

I am working in VS Code (with TypeScript) and it complains about not being able to find the angular2/di module.

However I do see a bind function defined in angular2/angular2.d.ts. If I change the import statement to the following, then the error goes away.

```
import {bind} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

Is the question in the title off-base and I am making some erroneous assumption?

If not, why do many samples reference one module to import the bind function from, yet I seem to be able to get it from a different module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because you looked at versions from older alphas. Look at [the angular2.ts file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/angular2.ts). Everything is exported from it. Also note that the d.ts is going to contain everything to resolve types in your IDE and at compilation time. What import does is actually importing the .js files.